# Onscroll function is not working for Chrome

Tags: javascript

The below code is working fine for Firefox browser. But, not chrome. What is the issue in below code ?

```
window.onload = function()
{
   document.body.onscroll =  Test.callFn;
}

var Test = new function()
{
   this.callFn = function()
   {
      console.log("Calling this function");
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your body's `overflow` property set to?

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem today. You can change `document.body` to `window`:

```
window.onload = function()
{
   window.onscroll = function()
   {
      console.log("Calling this function");
   }
}
```

I noticed that in chrome `onscroll` event is working when `body` element has `onscroll` attribute, but in IE it's working when `html` element has `onscroll` attribute, so it's the best to assign `onscroll` event listener to `window` object.

PS. if you want to check how many pixels you scrolled - use `window.pageYOffset` instead of `document.body.scrollTop` (the same situation with chrome and IE as described above).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and it was because I had `overflow-x: hidden` assigned to the body. Removing this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want the `()` when you're assigning `callFn` as the onscroll handler.
You don't want to execute the function, you want to assign a reference to it.

In addition, onscroll for an entire document seems to work better cross-browser on the `window` object, rather than `document` or `document.body`.

```
window.onscroll = Test.callFn;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my typo. Initially, i have called the function that above format. But it does not working for only chrome.

Answer (score 5):

window.onscroll does not work at times when you style an element using the`height` property of css.

try using `min-height` or `max-height` instead.

Comment: I had height: 100vh for a div in a top level layout file. Changed it to min-height: 100vh and the scroll event starts firing in Chrome! :)

Answer (score 4):

One of the possibility is there are  two `window.onscroll` statements on your page that each statement calling different JS method. Check the  included files and all  the  methods that are in the page loading.

Comment: Thanks for your Great mention :)

Answer (score 4):

This might also happen when the height of `html` and `body` tags is set to 100% and the scroll event does not fire for window nor document. To check which element is scrolled I slightly modified [Aaron Mason's snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016740/onscroll-function-is-not-working-for-chrome#comment83082549_17016775) which wasn't working for me either:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, it works if you attach the event handler to the `document.onscroll` event:

`document.onscroll = function() { console.log('Works in Chrome!'); };`

Comment: It works in Chrome. Open a new tab (CTRL+T), open the developer tools (SHIFT+CTRL+I), copy/paste the code snippet above, and scroll the window: you will see "Works in Chrome!" appearing in the console.

Comment: You can't be serious. It simply does work in Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome 63.0.3239.108. I even tried setting the onscroll for every single element and got nothing: `document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(elem){elem.onscroll=function(){console.log(this);};});`

Comment: Well, Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **`window.onwheel`** function instead.

When you are using `window.onscroll` you have to first be able to scroll in the window. Hence, `window`.**`onscroll`**

The `window.onwheel` function is activated when whatever the mouse wheel is turning on the object. In the example, the object is window, so when you "scroll" in the window, it will run the function.

Also, you would want to remove <strike>`window.onload`</strike>, since that function only runs when the window is loaded.

A sample code for scrolling using the `window.onwheel` function would be this:

```js
window.onwheel = ()=>{
    alert("Scrolling")
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll here!</p>
```

You can also find the direction of scrolling (up, down) by doing the following:

```js
window.onwheel = (e)=>{
    //deltaX shows the amount scrolled right-left
    //deltaY shows the amount scrolled up-down
    console.log(e.deltaX(), e.deltaY())
}
```

Hope this helps.